# LLCP connection-oriented and connectionless + P2P NFC

Tags: android, nfc, osi

in LLCP there are 2 transport possibilities:

- connection-oriented
- connectionless

Does someone know which kind of this LLCP transports is used in combination with:

- NPP
- SNEP

NPP is just 1-way, so maybe it is combines with connections-oriented because of the acknowledgements, but i don't know.
SNEP has this acknowledgements for confirming received packages, so maybe it is combines with connectionless LLCP to avoid redundancy, but I'm not sure.

I hope you can help me, 
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found the following in the file target.c of Google's Source Code:

```
/*
 * Services a LLCP conversation with a BEAM device, such as Android ICS, or
 * an NPP device, such as Android GB. First attempts to connect on well known
 * SNEP service. If that request is denied, connects to the NPP service by
 * name. Once connected, sends the NDEF record via the available protocol.
 *
 * LLCP is a connection oriented protocol. The state is managed by llcp.c.
 * The basic flow is as follows:
 * 1) Connect on SNEP service (4)
 * 2) If fails, connect on NPP service by name
 * 3) Once connected, send payload via SNEP or NPP
 * 4) If SNEP, wait for acknowledgment (NPP does not ackonwledge)
 * 5) Disconnect
 *
 * Arguments:
 *   resp - Buffer to be reused to receive LLCP commands
 *   resp_len - Size of resp in bytes
 *   ndef - Data to send to peer, e.g. a NDEF record
 *   ndef_len - Length of payload in bytes
 *
 * Returns:
 *   true if all data was passed to peer, false on error or timeout
 */
```

Answer (score 0):

Both NPP and SNEP used Connection oriented LLCP channel